# Azure cloud service app (web role) goes down for ~10 mins occasionally due to Windows Updates? How can I schedule them?

Tags: windows, azure, schedule, azure-web-roles, automatic-updates

It seems to happen every couple months or so and while it auto-recovers on its own usually within ~10 minutes I'd still like to find out how to change the Windows Update schedule since it frequently occurs during business hours.

We have several web apps in various Azure subscriptions, and they all behave this way.  Once we get a notification that one goes down, the others usually go down over the next few days/week.

I used remote desktop to view the Event Viewer for the web role and see the following (this down time took place between 9:48am and 10:02am on the east coast, so definitely not ideal):

8/6/2020 1:48:15 PM - "Automatic Updates is now paused."

Followed by several services stopping, and then:

8/6/2020 1:52:53 PM - "The process C:\43..61\Setup.exe (RD..33) has initiated the restart of computer RD..3 on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Other (Planned)
Reason Code: 0x80000000
Shutdown Type: restart
Comment: "

8/6/2020 1:52:53 PM - "Automatic Updates is now resumed."

8/6/2020 1:53:10 PM - "The operating system is shutting down at system time ‎2020‎-‎08‎-‎06T13:53:10.614704600Z."

8/6/2020 1:53:12 PM - The operating system started at system time ‎2020‎-‎08‎-‎06T13:53:12.487679900Z.

Obviously it takes a while for everything to come back up, and I finally get notified that the site is back up about 9 minutes later.

Is there a way to specify when the Windows Updates should take place?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why are you using web roles? We have many web apps and use Azure App Service. We are yet to observe such an issue. App Service is a much newer service than web roles, and as such has quite a few advantages.

Comment: It's actually listed as "Cloud service (classic)", which I guess is the newer name Microsoft is calling what used to be web roles, sorry for the confusion...they change the names of their various services so often it's hard to keep track.  But it is what was created when publishing/deploying from Visual Studio using the Azure Cloud Service Project (.ccproj)

Comment: FYI, we use cloud services because we needed to install some dependencies on the server itself to support integration with a 3rd party component.

Comment: If you have any question about this, you also can raise a support ticket on portal.

Answer (score 0):

**I can tell you clearly that it is not possible to schedule windows updates.**

The windows update in this cloud services is about once a month. The time is not fixed. There is no way to control this.

[Azure Guest OS releases and SDK compatibility matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix)

***solution:***

We can create 2 webroles so that we can solve the situation that the program is closed due to windows update.

***principle:***

Create 2 webroles to load balance the server pressure. When the windows is updated, it will not be updated at the same time, but a planned instance update ends, and the next instance update is performed.

In this way, as long as you create `>=2` webrols, there will be 2 instances, so that the program can guarantee that it will not stop due to updates.